# Letsencrypt domain validation fail on Parse.com hosting

Tags: parse-platform, lets-encrypt

Letsencrypt domain validation requires folder with dot in it like .well-known/acme-challenge but Parse.com hosting's public folder deploy ignores folders with name start with dot char. 
Dot character seem to be mandatory for the ACME verification. 
Parse.com team should consider supporting folder name with dot to support Letsencrypt. Time being I wish to know any other alternative solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather sounds like a feature request, that should be directed at parse directly.

Comment: I'm looking for alternate solutions too for time being

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make it clear that you are looking for a workaround. Otherwise the question does seem like a feature request.

Comment: @Blackwood As you have suggested I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a odd workaround but might work if Parse.com allows you to issue redirects

Let´s Encrypt client will follow http redirects so you can redirect it to another place which contains the .well-known challenge. You might have to run it in standalone and put challenge by hand at the other place but it will work. You can try to redirect it to S3 bucket on Amazon AWS for instance or to your own PC running a miniserver.

But I don´t know Parse.com and if they support you to configure http redirects.

good luck.